# Identify the implicit cast and explicit cast

Tags: c, casting

I would appreciate it if anyone can answer my question.
Identify the implicit cast and explicit cast?

```
int a = 2, b = 3;

float f = 2.5;
double d = -1.2;
int int_result;
float real_result;
```

Comment: This is pretty unclear. What exactly would you like to do? For example: what's up with the variables `int_result` and `real_result`?

Also, having a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help might help you write better questions and get better answers.

Comment: First, is this for a C or C++ class?  It's best to put the language into the tags.  Second, is this a trick question?  There is no explicit cast.

Comment: I see one implicit cast and no explicit casts - are you sure you included all the code ?

Answer (score 3):

Formally, the question makes no sense from the terminological point of view. There's no such thing as "implicit cast". The whole point of the term *cast* is that it designates an explicitly-requested *conversion*. Cast is the type conversion explicitly requested by the operator of the `(type)` form.

What in this case can be explicit or implicit is called *conversion*. This is what was probably meant by the author of the question, but screwed up by their poor knowledge of C terminology.

In your code sample only one initialization requires a conversion. And, of course, that conversion is implicit, since there are no *casts* in your code whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, casts are always explicit.  What is implicit is *conversion*.  When an object is assigned a value that is not the type of the object, then one of the two things can happen:

1. the type of the value is "compatible" with the type of the object, i.e., the standard allows such an assignment.  Then, the compiler does a conversion for you.  This is called implicit conversion.  For example, `size_t i = -1;` has an implicit conversion of the `int` −1 to `size_t`.
2. otherwise, the compiler must issue a diagnostic in this case, and you need a cast to do the assignment.  The result of such a cast is either implementation-defined or undefined.

Given the above, [you rarely need casts in C](http://www.cpax.org.uk/prg/writings/casting.php).  One of the times you need a cast might be in a variadic function because the compiler cannot do the implicit conversion for you.  Another example would be to convert an integer to a pointer in an implementation-defined way.

Once more, there is no such thing as *implicit* cast.

Answer (score 0):

well, this is actually a home work in C class, and there was an example answer given for the first line wirtten in the above, which i didnt undersand:which was,

```
int_result = a * f;
// a is casted implicitly to float by the multiplication operation a*f,
// the product is then casted implicitly to int by the = (assignment) operation.
real_result = a * f;
real_result = (float) a * b;
d = a + b / a * f;
d = f * b / a + a;
```

thanks again, look forward your replies!! :)

Comment: Are you the original poster?  Posting from two new accounts is odd, and if you used the same one you could edit the question.

Comment: Also, I just edited it to format it better.

Comment: What the comment says in the above code is completely and totally bogus. Firstly, what happens there is not a "cast", but an implicit *conversion*. Secondly, both `a` and `f` are converted to type `double`, not `float` before multiplication. Then the `double` result is converted to `int`. C language never performs arithmetic operations in `float` (or `short` or `char`). The type is always promoted at least to `double` (or `int` for integers).

Answer (score -1):

int a = 2, b = 3;

float f = 2.5;

double d = -1.2; //This is an implicit cast.

int int_result;

float real_result;

There is no explicit cast in above statements.